# Xampp doesnt update my php-code

Tags: php, web, xampp

I recently started coding in php again. Well, and my problem is simple. Xampp or whatsoever is not updating my file, but if I construct annother error on purpose.

Code:

```php
public function getPosts($from, $to){
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM entries LIMIT ". $from .",". $to;
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $posts = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $p = "f";
            $i++;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        return $posts;
    }
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Post' (T_STRING), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\websitews\webapi\Post.php on
>   line 13

I was creating a new object of type Post, but there is nothing of such left - at all! `$p = "f";` was just a test if it would update after I deleted `$p = new Post();`

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? ^.^ Thanks! I'm freaking out on this!

Answer (score 1):

You never ended your SQL query

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM entries LIMIT ". $from .",". $to;
```

should be

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM entries LIMIT '". $from ."','". $to"'";
```

See what that does for you

Comment: also in the future, it would help us to know what part of the code "line 13" is :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didnt change anything. Line13 is the part with $p = "f";. I even restarted my computer and the same error appeared again, though there is no string in my code saying "Post".

Comment: @JustBasti I'll look into it some more, have you considered using WAMP? just to try a different server.

Comment: Haven't heard of it. WIll take a look on it if I encounter more problems. Fixed mine now. I just deleted and copied all the files to a new location. Fixed my problem :)

Comment: Then it probably was an issue with xampp, an odd one at that. I personally use WAMP. I tend to have fewer problems with it. http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/